# Angular 2 - Use same resolver for parent and child routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2.0 (stable version) app where one of the entities is `project`. For each of these `projects`, I have its details spread accross different sections / routes:

- `project/:id/overview`
- `project/:id/documents`
- `project/:id/logs`
- etc

The API for `project` returns most of the data in a single call, so I need to call it once, and make it available for the different child routes.

My routes looks like:

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: 'projects',                   component: ProjectsComponent },
    { path: 'project/new',                component: NewProjectComponent },
    {
        path: 'project/:id',
        component: ProjectDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
            project: ProjectDetailResolve
        },
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'overview',           component: ProjectOverviewComponent },
            { path: 'documents',          component: DocumentsComponent },
            { path: 'logs',               component: LogsComponent },
        ]
    }
]);
```

`ProjectDetailComponent` currently gets the project data successfully, with the Resolver (no problems there) by using:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.forEach((data: { project: any }) => {
        this.project = data.project;
    });
}
```

But I need to pass that same project down to the child routes as it doesn't make sense to trigger another API call for each of those routes.

I've tried using the same `ngOnInit` code in the child components, thinking that maybe the Angular Router would pass the route data as well, but no success.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use 'parent' property of 'route' to get data from parent resolvers.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.data.subscribe(data => {
        this.project = data.project;
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this possible in the current version, too: ``this.route.parent.snapshot.data['mydata']``if I want a synchronous access?

Answer (score 6):

Depend on how far is your resolve object by the component hierarchy you can reach it by the `parent`property.

**Examples:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.data.subscribe(data => this.project = data.project);
}
```

***Or without subscription***

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.project = this.route.snapshot.parent.data['project'];
}
```

P.S.
Keep in mind that in case you component is deeper than one level, you can chain `parent` property unlimited amount of times. Like `this.route.snapshot.parent.parent.data['project']`. Cheers!